# Prevent Eclipse RSE Remote Systems view from auto-selecting file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rse

I use the Eclipse RSE plugin to access files residing on a remote server (via SSH). There's one behaviour of this plugin which I find incredibly annoying: whenever I switch tabs in the editor, the Remote System view automatically selects the corresponding file in the tree... but, it does that by closing all nodes in the tree, and then re-opening to the file, but only to that file's node. All others remain closed. If I have other nodes open because I'm frequently using files from those nodes, I then have to dig through the tree again.

I assume that this is not just happening for me? Is anyone aware of any way to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toggle `link with editor` button in Remote systems view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea how I missed that.. though the image doesn't really indicate the function too well.